# подскажите пожалуйста, функция "click_tile1" выполняется один раз, как сделать чтобы она повторялась три раза

Tags: javascript

```
var bet = 50;

var bigBet = bet/.039; 
bigBet = Math.ceil(bigBet);

var risky_bet_chance = 76;

var interval = 800; 

var restart, tile1, timeout1, timeout2, timeout3;

$('.quarter').first().find('button').click(); 

start_game();
function start_game() {

    var risky_bet = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);    

    if(restart == 1){
        if (risky_bet < risky_bet_chance) {
            $('#bet').val(1.5*bigBet);
        } else {
            $('#bet').val(bigBet);
        }
        restart = 0;
    } else {    
        if (risky_bet < risky_bet_chance) {
            $('#bet').val(1.5*bigBet);
        } else {
            $('#bet').val(bet);
        }       
    }
    $('#start_game').click();
    timeout1 = setTimeout(click_tile1, interval)

} // end of function start_game()

function click_tile1() {

    var tile1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 25) + 1);    
    //search_last_bomb();
    $('.game_left').first().find('li[data-tile='+tile1+']').click();
    $('.game_left [data-tile="'+tile1+'"]').click();
    setTimeout(function(){
        if($('.game_left').first().find('li[data-tile='+tile1+']').hasClass('bomb')){
            var bal = $('.balance .num').html();
            bal = $.trim(bal);
            bal = bal.replace(',','');
            bal = parseInt(bal);
            //bal = bigBet // practice mode

            if(bal < bigBet){
                stopgame();
            } else {
                restart = 1;
                start_game();
            }

        }else{          
            timeout2 = setTimeout(cashout, interval);
        }
    }, interval);

} // end of function click_tile()

function cashout() {
    $('.game_right').first().find('.cashout').click();
    timeout3 = setTimeout(start_game, interval);    
} // end of cashout

function stopgame(){
    clearTimeout(timeout1);
    clearTimeout(timeout2);
    clearTimeout(timeout3);
} // end of stopgame()

function search_last_bomb(){
    var has_chosen = 0;
    if($('.game_left').eq(1) != null && $('.game_left').eq(1).length > 0){
        $('.game_left').eq(1).find('.board').find('li').each(function(i,elem){
            if($(elem).hasClass('reveal')){
                has_chosen = 1;
                tile1 = $(elem).data('tile');
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    if(has_chosen == 0){
        tile1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 25) + 1);
    }   
} // end of searchLastBombTile()
```

Answer (score 1):

Вместо таймера нужно создать интервал

```
var interval = 800; 

var restart, tile1, timeout1, timeout2, timeout3;

$('.quarter').first().find('button').click(); 

start_game();
function start_game() {

    var risky_bet = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);    

    if(restart == 1){
        if (risky_bet < risky_bet_chance) {
            $('#bet').val(1.5*bigBet);
        } else {
            $('#bet').val(bigBet);
        }
        restart = 0;
    } else {    
        if (risky_bet < risky_bet_chance) {
            $('#bet').val(1.5*bigBet);
        } else {
            $('#bet').val(bet);
        }       
    }
    $('#start_game').click();
    //------------// Вместо таймера создаём интервал //------------//
    var timeout1N = 0;
    timeout1 = setInterval(function() {
        click_tile1;
        if(timeout1N == 2){
             clearInterval(timeout1);
        }else{
             timeout1N++;
        };
    }, interval)

} // end of function start_game()

function click_tile1() {

    var tile1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 25) + 1);    
    //search_last_bomb();
    $('.game_left').first().find('li[data-tile='+tile1+']').click();
    $('.game_left [data-tile="'+tile1+'"]').click();
    setTimeout(function(){
        if($('.game_left').first().find('li[data-tile='+tile1+']').hasClass('bomb')){
            var bal = $('.balance .num').html();
            bal = $.trim(bal);
            bal = bal.replace(',','');
            bal = parseInt(bal);
            //bal = bigBet // practice mode

            if(bal < bigBet){
                stopgame();
            } else {
                restart = 1;
                start_game();
            }

        }else{          
            timeout2 = setTimeout(cashout, interval);
        }
    }, interval);

} // end of function click_tile()

function cashout() {
    $('.game_right').first().find('.cashout').click();
    timeout3 = setTimeout(start_game, interval);    
} // end of cashout

function stopgame(){
    clearTimeout(timeout1);
    clearTimeout(timeout2);
    clearTimeout(timeout3);
} // end of stopgame()

function search_last_bomb(){
    var has_chosen = 0;
    if($('.game_left').eq(1) != null && $('.game_left').eq(1).length > 0){
        $('.game_left').eq(1).find('.board').find('li').each(function(i,elem){
            if($(elem).hasClass('reveal')){
                has_chosen = 1;
                tile1 = $(elem).data('tile');
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    if(has_chosen == 0){
        tile1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 25) + 1);
    }   
} // end of searchLastBombTile()
```